# What's the best way to store data for different lists?

Tags: swift, core-data, storage

So I'm new to programming and wondered what would be the optimal way to store data if I want to be able to save the data to different lists and easily be able to move data from each list to each other.
Should I use an array?
By the way I'm saving with core data at the moment.
[image: not sure if this helps :S]

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core data is fine. Another option is to use a local database in your Document folder. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift) is a tutorial for `sqlite` database. You can also use Github libraries.

You can also save the data in a server so that user wont lose it. You can either create your own RESTful server, or use a free popular one called [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/)

Comment: Ok thanks but what if I want to combine two list like week list should show the today list also because today is in the week but it should not show week task in the today list. Should I then use different lists to be able to separate them?

Comment: @J-Doe Well there is no right answer. Personally in this case I will keep Week and Day in one list because they should both have the same object inside the list and you can easily filtered out which one is from today. In your situation, I will have one list for Today and Week, and another list for Todo list